# Progress Bar in Webview

Tags: java, android, webview, progress-bar, loading

I am having troubles getting this progress bar to work properly. can any body help me with the source, is there something im missing?

```
 web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

        //ADDING THIS RESOLVED THE PROGRESS BAR ACTUALLY LOADING.
        web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        progressBar.setProgress(progress); } 
        });
        //ADDING THIS RESOLVED THE PROGRESS BAR ACTUALLY LOADING.

        WebSettings websettings = web.getSettings();
        websettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        websettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        websettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        websettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        websettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        websettings.setSavePassword(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Then Later in the code

```
    //Loading the Actual Webpage
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;

    }
    //web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
         progressBar.setProgress(progress);

    }




    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

The webview itself works just fine, im just trying to have a horizontal loading bar, similar to browsers like dolphin, chrome, etc.

Here is the layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/bgapp"
 android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <include
    android:id="@+id/inc_blue"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    layout="@layout/inc_enphase_bar_with_title_buttons" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="8dip" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.15"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical" >

</WebView>
```

Im not getting any errors or antying so no logcat, its just actually loading, it displays the progress bar when a webpage is loading but no animation or actually movement of loading.

Comment: put  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 int the inPageStarted callbasck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also set intermediate progress by using

```
progressBar.setProgress(int);
```

for the progress to be shown. All you are doing is showing and hiding the view

Edit:
 <strike>Add below code.</strike>

```
   @Override
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
     progressBar.setProgress(progress);
   }
```

Sorry you need a webchromeclient for this. So use like below. Put it just below

```
web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
//add this below line
web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
   }
 });
```

Check [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) Doc, it has an example.

Comment: Where would i place `progressBar.setProgress(int);` inside my myWebclient, and do any of you know is it better to use chromeclient stuff inside webview?

Comment: i am not too sure of chromeclient, have never worked on it. Override the onProgresschanged of the WebViewClient class

Comment: I have update my source with what i believe was what you were suggestion, you mind taking a look. feel free to edit the code to if i made a mistake.

Comment: I have edited the code. donot multiply by 1000, 1000 is used by Activity title progress bar. In case of Progressbar max is 100, so you can directly pass progress variable of onprogresschanged

Comment: Im having trouble getting the `web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {` to work with my existing source code. I updated it my source, and outcommented it due errors im getting, any ideas what i need to added, maybe i dont have the right formatting

Comment: not inside class, put it where you set the webclient. i have edited code